# What could cause a spike in GAE instances?

Tags: google-app-engine

I noticed that I finally almost went over my daily billing quota. It was purely caused by a spike in the number of running instances. I looked at the number of instances and there was a spike of 8 instances. I then looked at the requests / second at the same time period to see if there was a corresponding spike in the number of requests and there was not.

I am using Java, and I have threadsafe set to true in my appengine-web.xml.

Here are the two graphs showing the spike in instances and the relatively stable requests/second graph.

[image: Instances]

[image: Requests / second]

Update - I just discovered that the bytes/second graph seems to correspond. So could it be that a request that returns a relatively large result causes the instances to spike?

[image: Bytes/second]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google constantly tweaks App Engine's scheduler, so I cannot be sure that my response is 100% accurate. Anyway, this is how I see it.

When an instance is busy processing a long-running request that consumes its bandwidth, a new request will result in a new instance being created. This instance, however, is not immediately available - the startup time can range from 6 seconds to 40 seconds (for Java runtime) depending on the application. When new requests continue to hit during this startup time, a single long-running request may result in more than one instance being spun off. This situation is less likely for apps with a large number of instances as free threads become available more frequently and a single request is less likely to have a big impact.